# how to extract topic models result with its weights in R mallet

Tags: r

Anyone please help me for extracting topic models results (topic terms) along with its weights.

this is my code

```
mallet.instances <- mallet.import(as.character(documents$id), as.character(documents$text), "custom_stopwords.csv", FALSE, token.regexp="\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")

n.topics <- 30

topic.model <- MalletLDA(n.topics)

topic.model$loadDocuments(mallet.instances)

vocabulary <- topic.model$getVocabulary()

word.freqs <- mallet.word.freqs(topic.model)

topic.model$setAlphaOptimization(20, 50)

topic.model$train(200)

topic.model$maximize(10)

doc.topics <- mallet.doc.topics(topic.model, smoothed=T, normalized=T)

topic.words <- mallet.topic.words(topic.model, smoothed=T, normalized=T)

topic.docs <- t(doc.topics)

topic.docs <- topic.docs / rowSums(topic.docs)

write.csv(topic.docs, "topics-docs.csv" )


topics.labels <- rep("", n.topics)

for (topic in 1:n.topics) topics.labels[topic] <-paste(mallet.top.words(topic.model, topic.words[topic,],                                                                      num.top.words=10)$words, collapse=",")              

topics.labels

write.csv(topics.labels, "topics-labels.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please take some time to create a proper reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please any one help me!

Comment: It can not be emphasized enough that a message is putting yourself at the
mercy of strangers. If someone has the wit and knowledge to answer your
question, they probably have other things they would like to do. Making your message clear, concise and user-friendly gives you the best hope of at least one of those strangers diverting their attention away from their life towards your problem.